# How fix error in module depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I try to add admob banner but encounter this error, what to do?

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

```
version = '1.0'
ext {
    appName = "my-gdx-game"
    gdxVersion = '1.9.3'
    roboVMVersion = '2.1.0'
    box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
    ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
    aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    admobVersion = '9.2.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
}
```

}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
}
```

}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

```
configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
    compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$admobVersion"
}
```

}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compile the adMob component:

> (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$admobVersion)

On the core module (That is compiled as a jar library) !

You need to move it to the Android module (That will be compiled as an AAR - Android Archive Library).